# jQuery disable input in other row when checkbox is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to enable/disable input when checkbox is checked. I have many sections in my site with the same structure so I know I need to use

```
this
```

construction. I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work. Anyone could help me?

```js
$('.component-other').on('click', function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (isChecked) {
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.component-other-value').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.component-other-value').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="sause-oth">Other</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sause" id="sause-oth" class="enable component-other">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row input-row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other" class="component-other-value" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Type text here">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="sause-oth">Other</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sause" id="sause-oth-1" class="enable component-other">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row input-row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other-1" class="component-other-value" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Type text here">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Andreas I know. I just copied elements to make 2 sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest `.row` is not enough. You have to step one more layer up the DOM.

```js
$('.component-other').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.container')
           .find('.component-other-value')
           .prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="sause-oth">Other</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sause" id="sause-oth" class="enable component-other">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other" class="component-other-value" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Type text here">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="sause-oth">Other</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sause" id="sause-oth-1" class="enable component-other">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other-1" class="component-other-value" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Type text here">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want!